# Not all code paths return a value?

Tags: c#, return

I keep getting the error as named in the title, but it seems that a value for l is returned no matter what. Whats the issue here? I have an else statement to handle  the out l if there is no change with it:

```
    public int validate(int zip, int i, out int l)
{
    if ((zip < 10000) || (zip > 99999))
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Input not accepted. Zips are 6-digits long.");
        error = true;

    }
    else {
        listzip[i] = zip;
        error = false; }

    for (int g = 1; (g <= (i - 1)); g++)
    {
        if (listzip[i] == listzip[g])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Repeated zip detected, please re-enter.");
            if (!error) error = true;
        } else error = false;
    }


    if (error)
    {
        l = i--; // forces a step back if an error was detected
    }else l = i;
}
```

Comment: Your method has return type `int` but there is no `return` statement in your code.

Comment: What dtb said.  I assume the confusion stems from the fact that you're using an out parameter, and you believe that setting that is the same as returning a value.  It is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of your method is `int`, so you need to return an `int` value from your method. You should use the [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) statement to return the value ([see the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx))

If the method's signature was `public void validate(...)` then no [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) statement was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your method return types is an `int`, but in your method there is no *return value*.

If you don't want to return any value from your method, define your return type as `void`. Like;

```
public void validate(int zip, int i, out int l)
{
  // No need return statement
}
```

Check out *return* statement from **[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)**

> The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it
>   appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return
>   an optional value. If the method is a **void** type, the return statement
>   can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is declared such that, C# compiler expects you `return` an `int` value. But from the looks of your code, you probably want the return type to be `void` instead of `int`.

```
public void validate(int zip, int i, out int l)
{
    if ((zip < 10000) || (zip > 99999))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input not accepted. Zips are 6-digits long.");
        error = true;
    }
```